# Getting an error in flow (URI) in step "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint"

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, json, power-automate, microsoft-flow

I have created a flow.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is, create item in SharePoint when MS-CRM Account records is updated. But, I'm getting an error. The expression is not valid (URI).

[image]

I'm Attaching a screenshot of my list name(customer):

[image]

I have referred above link:https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/9832/creating-sharepoint-list-items-in-microsoft-flow-using-a-rest-api

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use apostrophe instead of double quotes in the URI.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using SharePoint REST API to create list item in SharePoint.

I will suggest you to use [Create item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#create-item) action to create a list item in SharePoint.

For resolving your error:

You need to use your endpoint like below in **Uri**:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('customer')/items
```

**Additional**: Refer [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Flow-creating-new-SharePoint-list-item-quot-Created-By-quot-help/td-p/85391) and [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Use-MS-Flow-to-create-a-new-item-in-a-sharepoint-list-using-data/td-p/287562) to know how you can configure create item action in flow.

Comment: Because I have a requirement to use only SharePoint API to create list item. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You're welcome. In that case, Uri format specified in my answer should work for you. don't forget to add `/items` at the end of list endpoint Uri. Asking just out of curiosity, is there any benefit of using SP REST API call instead of using default SharePoint connector action?